# namespace definition changes mimetype

Tags: php

i noticed strange mimetype behaviour when defining namespace (alias).whenever i define a namespace or an alias containing `\input` the mimetype of the php source file changes from `text/x-php` to `text/x-tex`.

A minimal **example.php** could look like this where the surroundings of `\input` doesn't matter.

```
<?php namespace \input; ?>
```

When running `file --brief --mime-type example.php` the mimetype `text/x-tex` is printed instead of the expected one `text/x-php`.

As soon as the backslash before `input` is removed the mimetype switches back to `text/x-php`.

**Can anybody confirm this behaviour?

Does anybody know a reason why this is happening?

Does anybody got a fix/workaround for this except changing the namespace itself?**

Comment: I don't see a reason of this automatic change except if your editor try to deduce itself the mime type from the content. There's probably a way to enforce it.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte i tried to change the namespace with `vim` and `nano`. with both editors i encountered this behaviour

Comment: Paul Crovella is right, the file utility probably tries a "best candidate list" to deduce the mime type from the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` utility uses just some heuristics based on the *file contents*. In your case, it sees that

- the file is a plain text file (no binary)
- contains the string `\input`, which is a predefined macro in [TeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TeX)

And it seems that somehow the `\input`=TeX takes precedence over `<?php`=PHP.

The `file` utility does not look at file extensions.
Also, this has nothing to do how you save the file or which editor you use. It is just the contents that matter for `file`.

However, this does not change how the PHP interpreter, webserver or browser handles your file.

(Somehow related: [File on php showing HTML document](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/308112/file-on-php-showing-html-document/308117#308117))

Comment: the inbuilt php function `mime_content_type()` does evaluate to `text/x-tex` as well. so it simply invokes the `file` utility as well?

Comment: From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mime-magic.php): "This extension is derived from Apache mod_mime_magic, which is itself based on the `file` command […]"

Comment: aight. thanks for pointing to a documentation. upvoted and marked as answered. thanks. so unless file is changing its precedence over the tags mentioned one needs to avoid using `\input` in namespace definitions.